# rollup-plugin-vue error of 'Undefined variable' when using scss files

Tags: javascript, variables, sass, vuejs3, rollup

I'm trying to build my first library, and do it using `vue-sfc-rollup` with Vue 3, SCSS and Typescript. I'm using scoped scss in my Vue components.

I'm running into an error when building:

```
[!] (plugin vue) Error: Undefined variable.
  ╷
2 │ @each $name, $content in $theme-colors {
  │                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/components/elements/ButtonLarge.vue 2:26  root stylesheet
```

I encountered this error using the default `baseConfig` of `vue-sfc-rollup` with the default `PostCSS` config. But I have also attempted using `style()`, `scss()`, and different `PostCSS()` configs, etc. but it all results in the same error. I don't want to pollute this post with all the failed attempts. I'm using `vue: { preprocesssStyles: true }` for the `rollup-plugin-vue` config.

I *think* it's a matter of not having my global scss files getting imported during the Rollup build? I'm hoping to have the scoped scss injected into the JavaScript build file instead of having extracted .css files (I think? Unless it doesn't matter?), but I'm not familiar enough with Rollup to figure out how to import my style files (located at `src/styles/vars.scss`) where the `$theme-colors` variable is at (if that's the problem). I've been Googling for a couple days now without great results.

Here is how the `$theme-colors` variable is being used in my Vue components.

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
@each $name, $content in $theme-colors {
  // sass stuff using the $name and $content variables...
}
```

I apologize if I missed any information here; just let me know and I'll try to update the post with it. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Curious if no one is responding because I've possibly left out important information or didn't explain the problem well enough? Please let me know if that's the case - I'd love to get some ideas from others who have had success with Vue 3, Roll-up, scoped CSS and scss variables!

Comment: Hey  Kelly, did you find a solution to this? Experiencing the same problem

Comment: No, never figured it out. Had to move away from Roll-up to finish the project, but I'd still love to know the answer. Hope you can find it.